# Read sentences to char array from text file untill dot separator

Tags: c, arrays

I'm struggling to read sentences from text file into a char array.

Text file:

```
I am working at a gym.
Someone has stolen my 
backpack.
Everybody lies.
Hello
to
everyone.
```

Expected result (in array)

```
I am working at a gym.
Someone has stolen my backpack.
Everybody lies.
Hello to everyone.
```

Firstly I've tried to print these by using fgets fuction like that:

```
FILE* file = fopen("zdania.txt", "r");
char line[256];

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    printf("%s", line);
}

fclose(file);

return 0;
```

But it's bad solution due to the fact that it reads file line by line, and in my case I have to read sentence untill dot is found.

I've also tried to do something with getc function but it stops when the dot is found.

Comment: What about the input "My IP address is 127.0.0.1.”?

Comment: Yea, that's a good question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    if (ch == '.') {
        /* deal with dot */
    } else {
        /* deal with non dot */
    }
}
/* deal with possibly unfinished data */
```

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely. Anyway I've got problem with new line handling, I've added extra if condition when char equals to new line then do nothing. But now it produces extra tabulation in each next sentence.

Comment: You possibly need to identify sequences of two (or more) characters and act differently. A space after a dot should be treated differently that a space after a letter. Two newlines together should maybe be treated differently than twice the treatment for a single new line. ...

Comment: Okay, but how can I get next char to do it like you say?

Comment: Well, one common way to do that is with a *state machine*. Or you could keep two variables and write the conditions for both: `if (ch1 == '.' && ch2 == ' ') ...`

Answer (score 0):

you can read each `char` until `.` is found instead. maybe use `fread` instead of `fgets`, and go over the result array char by char to find `.`. another way is to use `strstr()`